# Collect the recently clicked 5 buttons in Word with VSTO C#

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, controls, vsto

Does anyone know how to collect the recently clicked 5 buttons, and save them to a new group in the Hometab for reusing? Using C# in VSTO.

It seems a simple thing, however, I find now way to dynamicly monitor the control event in the ribbon and get the ID.

Have searched for several weeks.
Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I don't think it's possible or at least I don't know about any way how to do that.
First there is no way how to easily monitor which button was pressed by any API Microsoft provides. You know, there is no command there is called for every button where you can hook your code and listen. I know that out there are amazing tools that can help you with things I originally thought are impossible [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/), [Watch Dog](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog/installation.htm), [MZ Tools](https://www.mztools.com/) but first, they are mainly for VBA, second it's probably not easy solution that you are looking for.

You would probably have to - somehow - mimic Office ribbon by your own ribbon => way too much work, use one callback, monitor it and determine the last 5 buttons.

Then you would have to change the Home tab by changing the ribbon XML which has two drawbacks

1, I believe it's not possible adding/removing buttons dynamically (you can use callback to change visibility but for adding/removing there is probably nothing)

2, you would have to restart the Office application to see your changes

As you see I'm not entirely sure it's impossible but I do see it as way too much work. 
Anyway I'd love to hear if there is a way how to do that, so please if you find any way do let me  know. Thanks